# Rails - URL helpers not working in mailers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer, urlhelper

I tried:

```
class MyMailer
  def routes
    Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  end

  def my_mail
    @my_route = routes.my_helper
    ... code omitted 
  end
```

Also inside mailer:

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

def my_mail
  @my_route = my_helper
```

Also, the simple way, in mailer template:

```
= link_to 'asd', my_helper
```

But then when I try to start console I get:

```
undefined method `my_helper' for #<Module:0x007f9252e39b80> (NoMethodError)
```

## Update

I am using the `_url` form of the helper, i.e. `my_helper_url`

Comment: Please accept one of the answers that helped you. :)

Answer (score 17):

For Rails 5, I included the url helpers into the my mailer file:

```
# mailers/invoice_mailer.rb
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers

class InvoiceMailer < ApplicationMailer
    def send_mail(invoice)
        @invoice = invoice
        mail(to: @invoice.client.email, subject: "Invoice Test")
    end
end
```

Comment: This solution can lead to issues. Specifically it can break `link_to` on other templates when deployed on heroku. I imagine this is a bug in rails, but a different workaround may be required, as it was with me. 
Reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34573087/link-to-does-not-work-in-production-heroku

Comment: @gdxn96 the problem happens when you start the server in production mode (what heroku does). It won't happen if you put the `include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` **within** the class `InvoiceMailer`

Answer (score 5):

Doing this broke my other routes.

```
# mailers/invoice_mailer.rb
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

Doing this is not the right way, this will break application as routes are reloading and routes will not be available is those are reloading

```
module SimpleBackend
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    Rails.application.reload_routes!
```

**Right answer is to use *_url and not *_path methods in email templates as explained below in Rails docs.**

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#generating-urls-in-action-mailer-views

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue but with a Concern, i was unable to use any of the url helpers in my code even using directly  `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.administrator_beverages_url` i was getting this error:

```
undefined method `administrator_beverages_url' for #<Module:0x00000002167158> (NoMethodError)
```

even unable to use the rails console because of this error the only way i found to solve this was to use this code in my Concern

```
module SimpleBackend
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern
    Rails.application.reload_routes! #this did the trick
.....
```

The problem was Rails.application.routes.url_helpers was empty at the moment of the initialization. I don't know the performance implication of using this but for my case this is a small application and i can take the bullet.

Answer (score 1):

In the mailer add

```
helper :my
```

or the helper you need

and it will load app/helpers/my_helper.rb & includes MyHelper

Enjoy

Comment: thanks, but I am tryin to use Rails route helpers. I suppose you are talking about helpers in `app/helpers`

Answer (score 0):

The rails route helpers are in `Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`. You should just be able to put 
`include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers` at the top of your class, though I haven't tested this

Comment: I tried this, that's weird. What is even weirder is that environment does not load if I use url helper, but I can: 1. comment line, 2. start server for example, 3. uncomment line 4. it works. But this is not going to work for real environment. As a temporal solution I am using static url: www.blahblahblah.com/...

Answer (score 0):

I came across this issue while working with a newly added route that seemed to be unavailable in my Mailer. My problem was I needed to restart all the workers, so they would pick up the newly added route. Just leaving this *footnote* in here in case someone runs into the same issue, it can be tricky to solve if you don't know this is happening.

Answer (score -1):

Please take a look at this blog which explains how you can make use of Rails.application.routes.url_helpers in the right manner.

http://hawkins.io/2012/03/generating_urls_whenever_and_wherever_you_want/

Comment: link returns 404...

Answer (score -2):

You need to use the `my_helper_url`

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: WTF is this comment @michaelb958 ?

Comment: I got here via the [Low Quality Posts queue](http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/stats), decided there wasn't *quite* enough in this answer, and recommended deletion with that canned comment. You are not required to agree with this; you may edit your post to improve it, or something.

Comment: So next time maybe read the answer and not copy&paste default msg. Guy is calling wrong method, that's all. Doesn't require more explanation.

Comment: I'm not a Rails expert, but I think that (OP) *I am using the `_url` form of the helper* means he's using `my_helper_url`. There is no revision timestamp given, so that info either shipped with the question or was edited in less than 5 minutes after posting. Ergo, this answer (half an hour ago) doesn't really help. (Feel free to disagree here.)

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I got angry. Anyway, I already learned that if a person SAYS they have something in code doesn't mean they do until code is pasted here. And in the pasted code I don't see _url "form"... ;)

Comment: hehehe, I haven't had seen a fight here.

Comment: O @juanpastas since you're here, can you confirm my suspicion? And if I am not right paste WHERE this error happens?

Comment: when trying to run console, or server,this is, when loading rails environment.

Comment: I can use helper when changing code at runtime... I am clueless why this happens

Comment: and can you give the full log?