# link_to does not work in production (Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I don't have any problems using link_to locally however, as soon as I deploy to Heroku I get the following error:

```
users#show (ArgumentError) "arguments passed to url_for can't be handled. Please require routes or provide your own implementation" 
app/views/users/show.html.erb:176:in `_app_views_users_show_html_erb__222687663100622833_69928454693640'
```

I am using ruby '2.2.0' and rails '4.2.0'

Any ideas on how to further debug this or replicate it locally?

---

Update 1. Here's the actual view code which displays pagination links. The resulting route should be /users/1?page=1 etc.

```
 <div class="row text-center">
   <%= will_paginate collection, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
 </div>
```

Comment: Please include the view code as well as the relevant entry in your `config/routes.rb` file.

Comment: @SeanHuber thanks for the response, see the edit above

Comment: whats in routes.rb file

Comment: @Abhinay here's the routes gist https://gist.github.com/andreitr/c85f7b7ee778d48b64ef

Comment: not sure this will help but have you tried this already http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32257545/how-to-use-url-helpers-in-rails-4-2

Answer (score 3):

The issue was with url_helpers included in one of my models - everything worked after I removed the following include.

```
include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
```

[Using the correct url_for method in a Rails engine spec](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20660604/using-the-correct-url-for-method-in-a-rails-engine-spec)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with ActiveAdmin in production environment. In my case the issue was with `ActionView::Helpers::FormTagHelper` included at root level in one of my helpers.

I solved it moving the include statement inside a class defined in the same file.